# How to horizontally shift a breakable tcolorbox?

Tags: tcolorbox, break-box

I'd like to display breakable `tcolorbox`es with all the same horizontal position in the pages, even if they are in items of lists. I could manage for non-breakable boxes but not for breakable ones, as shown by the following MCEs.

Hence the question: how to horizontally shift a breakable `tcolorbox`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\tcbuselibrary{breakable}

\newlength{\myshift}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1][]{
  text width=\textwidth,
  before={%
    \setlength{\myshift}{\linewidth-\textwidth-5.5mm}%
    \smallskip\par
    \noindent\hspace*{\myshift}%
  },
  #1
}

\newcommand{\test}[1][]{%
  Foo\par
  \begin{mybox}[#1]
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{mybox}
}

\begin{document}
\section{Non-beakable}
\test
\begin{enumerate}
\item \test
\end{enumerate}
\newpage
\section{Beakable}
\test[breakable]
\begin{enumerate}
\item \test[breakable]
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside list environments, the total left margin is stored in dimension `\@totalleftmargin`. Hence you can use `enlarge left by=-5.5mm-\@totalleftmargin` to replace `before=...`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\tcbuselibrary{breakable}

\makeatletter
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1][]{
  text width=\textwidth,
  enlarge left by=-5.5mm-\@totalleftmargin,
  #1
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\test}[1][]{%
  Foo\par
  \begin{mybox}[#1]
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{mybox}
}

\begin{document}
\section{Non-beakable}
  \test
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item \test
  \end{enumerate}
  \newpage

\section{Beakable}
  \test[breakable]
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item \test[breakable]
  \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Remark: `before=...` is only applied to the first box in a broken box sequence, see documentation of `tcolorbox`, sec. 18.1 *Technical Overview (of Library `breakable`)*.